# WHILE loop does not connect two boolean expressions with the OR (| |) operator

Tags: java

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    /** This program will evaluate a bank customer
    for a Home Loan Equaty 
    */

    public class HomeEquatyLoan
    {
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      String firstName,lastName, stringInput;   // Customer forst and last name.
      char usStatus ;                           //To hold 'y' or 'n;.
      String usStatus1;                         // Citizenship status of the customer.
      int ageCustomer, yearsWork;               // Customer data records.
      double annualSalaryMin = 35000;
      double annualSalaryMax = 75000;  // Customer salary.
      double annualSalary;
      // Get the customer information.

      firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter first name");

      lastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter last name");

      stringInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter customer age: "); //Customer age.

      ageCustomer = Integer.parseInt(stringInput);

      stringInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter customer years at work: "); //Customer years at work.

      yearsWork = Integer.parseInt(stringInput);

      stringInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter customer annual salary: "); //Annual salary.

      annualSalary = Double.parseDouble(stringInput);


      usStatus1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the US Citizen Status");

      usStatus = usStatus1.charAt(0); 



      while(annualSalary <= annualSalaryMin  || annualSalary > annualSalaryMax)
      {
         stringInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("The annual salary does not fall into the range" + 
                                   "allowed by State law." + "  Please enter the annual salary");

         annualSalary = Double.parseDouble(stringInput); 

      }


      while(yearsWork < 7)
      {
         stringInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("The customer years of work should be greater or" + 
                                   "equal that seven(7)." + "  Please enter years at work");


         yearsWork = Integer.parseInt(stringInput);

      }


      while((usStatus != 'y') || (usStatus != 'Y'))
      {



         usStatus1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("The customer must be an US Citizen in order to qualify" + 
                                   "for the loan.\n" + "  Please enter citizenship status");

         usStatus = usStatus1.charAt(0);              

      }


      //Display results

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, firstName +" "+ lastName + "\n"+ 
         "Age :" + ageCustomer +"\n" + "US Citizen: "+ usStatus + "\n" + "Years of Work: " + yearsWork +
         "\n" + "Annual Salary: $" + annualSalary + "\n" + "Qualify for the Home Equaity loan");

      System.exit(0);


   }  

}
```

Comment: You need to be more detailed in your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: if I use, while(usStatus != 'Y') it works perfect, but when i combine the two boolean expressions with the || (OR) logical operator, the loop never ends.

Answer (score 2):

```
 while((usStatus != 'y') || (usStatus != 'Y'))
```

That can only terminate if `usStatus` is simultaneously equal to both `'y'` and `'Y'`. It should be:

```
 while (usStatus != 'y' && usStatus != 'Y')
```

Comment: He could also use `while(Character.toLowerCase(usStatus) != 'y') { ... }`

Comment: or easier to read `while (Character.toUpperCase(usStatus) != 'Y')`

Comment: @FilipB.Vondrášek Indeed. Personally I would use `do/while` in this situation.

Comment: @Bohemian I don't see anything more readable about incorrectly changing the semantics from `while` to `if`, or arbitrarily changing the case being compared.

Comment: I works perfectly if I use: while (usStatus != 'y' && usStatus != 'Y')  ------ I dont understand why, because far as I know with the && operator both conditions should be fulfilled.                     Thank you so much!

Comment: @Avda7 Think about it. You were looping while the OR of two inequalities was true. That can only terminate when they are both false. For both inequalities to be false, the variable would have to have two different values at the same time. You need to loop while *either* of them is true, which is expressed by `&&`. That become false when they are both false, which is what you want.